# How to list "invisible" Auto Drafts?

Tags: attachments, editor, draft, listing

I noticed that when starting to create a new post, and only attach images and then when leavning the post for some reason, it won't show up in the list post view. However when you look in the Media Library you'll see that the image is attached to "Auto Draft" and that the post really exists.

Now, I find this useful, and would like to be able to list these Auto Drafts in the post view, but I don't really know what I need to do to list them.. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pasting this in your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'display_autosave_and_revisions' );
function display_autosave_and_revisions( $query )
{
    global $pagenow,$typenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $typenow == "post") {
        $query->query_vars['post_type'] = array('revision','post');
        $query->query_vars['post_status'] = 'any';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, nope, not showing up, are you sure that the ones I'm seeing in Media Library is auto saves or revisions?

Comment: No I'm not sure what you are seeing. But i am sure that auto-saves are revisions and I'm sure this code shows the revisions in the post listing

Comment: The thing is, I've disabled auto save, but I still get auto drafts when attaching images (I guess it's a media attachment thing).

Comment: When you upload an image the built-in uploader must have a post type ao if you haven't saved the post yet , WordPress creates an auto save.

Comment: Correction an auto-save is a `post_type=revision` and `post_status=auto-save` so i updated the code try now.

Comment: This is what I have right now: http://pastebin.com/dqhtZv8n and it works, it lists the drafts, however I also get this error message: 
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /ustorage/www/users/xxx/vhosts/xxx/wp-includes/post.php on line 817

Comment: Also, it lists a revision for a post that is publushed, and it cannot be removed (and it's not possible to tick multiple posts and remove them in bulk, it just gives the error message: Invalid Post Type)

Comment: that's the best you can get without hacking core files